# How does Pinterest implement Facebook like button?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, pinterest

When you like something on pininterest it will show in Facebook's activity something like "Name of a person" likes "something" on Pintrest.

How is that implemented and how can I do that on my own website?

Comment: It's an Open Graph action. Complete example here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/opengraph/actions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement facebook login and request the appropriate facebook publishing permissions from the user so that you can post your custom message to the user's facebook stream when they click YOUR like button.

Comment: It's that simple? I got the facebook login already implemented.